# How to pass my id click on CollectionViewCell to other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I have created **gallery view** in my app. In that add **segment controller** , first index is *table view* and second index is *collection view*. First index (*table view*) is proper work in my app, But second index (*collection view*) show array stored pictures but I want to click on *collection view cell* and move to another view and pass my UID to another *view controller*. I tried but could not pass my id. Please help. Thank you

## Segue method

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender      {

  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Tableview"]) {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table_view indexPathForSelectedRow];
      Detail_view *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      destViewController.uid_value = [id_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
  else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Collectionview"])
  {
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collection_view indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    collection *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    destViewController.uid_value = [id_ary[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.collection_view deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? can you elaborate ?

Comment: I want a pass my UID on click collection view cell to another view controller

Comment: you already did code i think that is perfect just make sure with your `indexpath` or `id_ary`

Comment: I update My question please wait

Comment: @MayankPatel I updated my code please see and help

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to improve your code rather then doing split arrays better to user NSObject class manage the array with Object Class for your solution use below code

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Collectionview"])
{
   NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collection_view indexPathsForSelectedItems];
   collection *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths firstObject]; // you can also use firstObject rather then ObjectAtIndex:0
   destViewController.uid_value = [id_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.collection_view deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

take a **global indexPath** for ex. `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;` Now add this line in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` i.e.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  selectedIndexPath=indexPath;
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Collectionview" sender:self];
}
```

now in your `prepareForSegue` method-

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Collectionview"])
{
   collection *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
   destViewController.uid_value = [id_ary objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row]; 
   // or destViewController.uid_value = [id_ary[selectedIndexPath.section] objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
   [self.collection_view deselectItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO];    
}
```

hope this will solve your issue..:)